# Mahindra urdf file

Tags: gazebo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Someone suggested me to test the urdf file of mahindra model on gazebo, but i am not able to find any such urdf file on the net. Can anyone help me in this regards.

Thank you

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/250354/mahindra-urdf-file/) by [Ayush Sharma](https://answers.ros.org/users/28428/ayush-sharma/) on ROS Answers with karma: 41 on 2016-12-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is really a Gazebo question (and should be asked over at `answers.gazebosim.org`), but 2 seconds googling lead me to [github.com/kaustubhhiware/mahindra](https://github.com/kaustubhhiware/mahindra):

> Model demo world for Mahindra Rise Prize

> This world contains a small city with white markings along the rod to guide the bot , and also yellow parking slots in some positions.

> To run the world , first of all , you must have 3 things installed - ROS, Gazebo(generally preinstalled with ROS) and gazebo-ros packages . You need to type the following in your terminal after changing the working directory to your local directory - roslaunch mahindra mahindra.launch

Is that what you were looking for?

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-12-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Ayush Sharma](https://answers.ros.org/users/28428/ayush-sharma/) on 2016-12-21**:
Thank you for your reply.